# Translating String Constants to Virtual Machine Code

Tags: string, compilation, constants

I have a project for school to translate a jack program to vm code. We were given some vague instructions and left to do it on our own. 
I am having trouble with translating String constants to vm code.
 Say there's a command in the program as follows: 
`do Output.printString("Hello world!")`
The translation would be something like this:

```
push SOMETHING (I don't know what to put here) 
call Output.printString 1
```

How do I translate the string into vm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I figured out:
There are two functions used to create a string. `String.new` and `String.appendChar`.

To create a String, first call `String.new` with the length of the string as an argument. Then, call `String.appendChar` for each character, with the ascii value of the current character as an argument to the function.
So, for example, to create the string `"Hello World"`:

```
push constant 11 //this is the length of the word
call String.new 1
push constant 72 //ascii of h
call String.appendChar 2
//continue this for each character in the word
...
call Output.printString 1 //prints the string that we created
```